# Github Issue 'locked' event doesn't update the Issue itself

Tags: github, github-api

I'm using [GitHub API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to connect to a `repository` and get the list of issues that were update/created `since` a specific **date**. I use these [parameters](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#parameters) to get a filtered result:

- filter: all
- labels: bug
- state: all
- sort: updated
- direction: ascendent
- since: **date**

If i find any result, for each issue I get the [issue events](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/) that triggered a change (filtering for the ones that happened `since` **date**).

Everything works fine for every `issue event` except for **locked** and **unlocked**
events that, for some reason, don't update the issue `updated` field.

This leads to the inability to get then the list of issues that were updated `since` that specific **date** and therefore I don't check for the `issue events`.

Questions:

1. Is there a reason why these two events don't update the issue?
2. Is there an acceptable solution, except for the one where I should get all the issues and query them manually?

Comment: You can try and use E-Tag instead of Since to cache request.

Comment: That means that I should save somewhere a previous `Etag` in order to compare it or query the server like: `If-None-Match: "bfd85cbf23ac0b0c8a29bee02e7117c6"`. This would complicate a lot but it is indeed a solution.

Comment: But you already store last 'since' date, don't you?

Comment: Yes, but I store a single date, not `ETag`s for each issue.

Comment: Well, you can [List all events for repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/#list-events-for-a-repository) and store a single ETag for that request.

Comment: Anyone still reproducing this issue? I cannot. I [posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32933158/1420197).

Comment: @Advicer Hey, it seems you are Romanian brother!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today (4th of October, 2015), I cannot reproduce this issue. If it was reproducible when the question was posted, probably it was a bug, not a feature.

> Is there a reason why these two events don't update the issue?

They do update the issue (see the `updated_at` field) and the `since` parameter works fine.

> Is there an acceptable solution, except for the one where I should get all the issues and query them manually?

Just use the `since` parameter, the way how it is supposed to work, *but* keep in mind the timezone could be different. Since you're in Romania (like me! `:-)`) and your server could be into another timezone, you may want to modify the date to match the Romanian time. That's most probably your issue. Just add/substract few hours and see if that helps.

`curl`ing the issues, I cannot reproduce the behavior you have.

On the other side, you may want to use the `locked` parameter which is anyway updated.